# Instantiate abstract class using Anonymous functions in Php

Tags: php, oop, anonymous-function

In java, there is a possibility to create an object of abstract class if we implement abstract method at the time of object creation by using Anonymous functions, So is it also possible to have the ability in Php.

Comment: Try googling: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.abstract.php

Comment: Stop abusing abstract classes. In general, your code shouldn't even require abstract classes.

Comment: @tereško can you please elaborate a little bit on the fact, that abstract classes shouldn't be used? I find this subject interesting. Thank you.

Comment: @aendeerei well, I was exaggerating a bit. Many people use (well .. misuse) abstract classes for a single purpose - so that they have where to put the "shared methods". But that's wrong. If you have so much shared code, your classes should be refactored and probably at least one separate class would be extracted, that then you use as dependency (to pass in the construct) instead of extending.

Comment: @aendeerei As for when to actually use abstract classes, that's a bit tricky to explain. Ideally, the abstract class would have only one or two abstract methods (maybe even `protected and not `public`). Think for example, some `Adapter` class, where all the code is done, **except** for the  `protected function convert()`. And when you, in your project create a concrete class `ApiToInvoiceAdapter`, you need to only implement that one specific method to get a fully functioning whole.

Comment: @tereško I see. Extending on polymorphic functionality (adapter's `convert()`)): `abstract` classes provide default behaviour too. In my project, resp. in an `AbstractView` I implement a default `load()`/`render()` functionality, in order to load/render templates without the need of any template engine. If I want to use one, then I correspondingly override the two methods. >>

Comment: @tereško >> I can do this by defining the two methods as abstract, or, actually - in this second I'm beeing enlightened by your proposal :-) - by creating a "default" template class - to be injected in a view in a without-template-engine-situation - and a template interface defining the contract for all future template implementations. >>

Comment: @tereško >> Beeing interested I recherched a bit and found a nice discussion on the subject too: [Are abstract classes-methods obsolete?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/94887/are-abstract-classes-methods-obsolete). Thank you for taking your time to share your perspective with me!

Comment: In abstract classes it's not about over riding, but actually not knowing/caring about the final implementation. For example, in a recent project I had an abstract [Collection](https://github.com/teresko/palladium/blob/master/src/Palladium/Component/Collection.php) class (glorified array-object), where the `buildEntity()` is abstract. The rest of code doesn't really care how the concrete methods will be implemented.

Answer (score 0):

Pre PHP 7 **NO**. The feature was only added in  PHP 7

https://wiki.php.net/rfc/anonymous_classes